# How do I make NHibernate cache fetched child collections?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, syscache2

I've got a fairly simple criteria query that fetches child collections, like so:

```
var order = Session.CreateCriteria<Order>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", id))
    .SetFetchMode("Customer", FetchMode.Eager)
    .SetFetchMode("Products", FetchMode.Eager)
    .SetFetchMode("Products.Category", FetchMode.Eager)
    .SetCacheable(true)
    .UniqueResult<Order>();
```

Using NH Prof, I've verified that this makes just one round trip to the database (as expected) with a cold cache; however, on successive executions, it retrieves only the `Order` from the cache and then hits the database with a SELECT(N+1) for every child entity in the graph, as in:

```
Cached query: SELECT ... FROM Order this_ left outer join Customer customer2 [...]
SELECT ... FROM Customer WHERE Id = 123;
SELECT ... FROM Products WHERE Id = 500;
SELECT ... FROM Products WHERE Id = 501;
...
SELECT ... FROM Categories WHERE Id = 3;
```

And so on and so forth. Clearly it's not caching the *whole* query or graph, only the root entity. The first "cached query" line actually has all of the `join` conditions that it's supposed to - it's definitely caching the *query itself* correctly, just not the *entities*, apparently.

I've tried this using the SysCache, SysCache2, and even HashTable cache providers and I always seem to get this same behaviour (NH version 3.2.0).

Googling turned up a number of ancient issues, such as:

- [NH-195: Child collections are not being stored in the second level cache](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-195)
- [Syscache2 2nd level cache: Child coll. objects requeried](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2368642&sid=80db14f4554220de0bcbef3e84b58399)
- [Weird differences between SysCache and SysCache2](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2368641#2368641)
- [NHibernate – Beware of inadvisably applied caching strategies](http://ayende.com/blog/4046/nhibernate-beware-of-inadvisably-applied-caching-strategies) (Ayende - of course he only bothers to mention what *not* to do, not how to fix it...)

However, these all seem to have been fixed a long time ago, and I get the same bad behaviour regardless of which provider I use.

I've read through the [nhibernate.info documentation on SysCache and SysCache2](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/caches.html#NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2) and there doesn't seem to be anything I'm missing. I've tried adding `cacheRegion` lines to the `Web.config` file for all tables involved in the query, but it doesn't change anything (and AFAIK those elements are just to *invalidate* the cache, so they shouldn't matter anyway).

With all of these super-old issues that all seem to be fixed/resolved, I figure this can't possibly *still* be a bug in NHibernate, it must be something that I'm doing wrong. But what?

Is there something special I need to do when combining fetch instructions in NHibernate with the second-level cache? What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you using a StatelessSession?

Comment: @Origin: No, in practice this is part of a sequence of future queries and those are not available in stateless sessions. Anyway, a stateless session wouldn't behave this way, it would just execute the original query every time.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I did manage to figure this out, so other folks can finally get a straight answer:

To sum it up, I've been confused for a while on the difference between the second-level cache and the query cache; Jason's answer is technically correct but it somehow didn't click for me. Here is how I would explain it:

- The query cache keeps track of *which entities* are emitted by a query. It does *not* cache the entire result set. It's the equivalent of doing a `Session.Load` on a lazy-loaded entity; it knows/expects that one exists but doesn't track *any* other information about it unless specifically asked, at which point it will actually load the *real* entity.
- The second-level cache tracks the actual *data* for each entity. When NHibernate needs to load any entity by its ID (by virtue of a `Session.Load`, `Session.Get`, lazy-loaded relationship, or, in the case above, an entity "reference" that's part of a cached query), it will look in the second-level cache first.

Of course this makes perfect sense in hindsight, but it's not so obvious when you hear the terms "query cache" and "second-level cache" being used almost interchangeably in so many places.

Essentially there are two sets of two settings each that you need to configure in order to see the expected results with query caching:

#### 1. Enable both caches

In XML configuration, this means adding the following two lines:

```
<property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="cache.use_query_cache" >true</property>
```

In Fluent NHibernate, it's this:

```
.Cache(c => c
    .UseQueryCache()
    .UseSecondLevelCache()
    .ProviderClass<SysCacheProvider>())
```

Please note the `UseSecondLevelCache` above because (at the time of this posting) it is **never** mentioned on the [Fluent NHibernate wiki page](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Database_configuration); there are several examples of enabling the query cache but not the second-level cache!

#### 2. Enable caching for each entity

Just enabling the second-level cache does pretty much nothing, and this is where I got tripped up. The second-level cache has to be not only enabled but *configured for every single individual entity class that you want cached*.

In XML, this is done inside the `<class>` element:

```
<cache usage="read-write"/>
```

In Fluent NHibernate (non-automap), it's done in the `ClassMap` constructor or wherever you put the rest of your mapping code:

```
Cache.ReadWrite().Region("Configuration");
```

This has to be done for *every* entity that is going to be cached. It's probably possible to set up in one place as a convention, but then you pretty much miss out on the ability to use regions (and in most systems you don't want to cache transactional data as much as configuration data).

And that's it. It's really not that hard to do but surprisingly difficult to find a good, complete example, especially for FNH.

---

One last point: The natural consequence of this is that **it makes eager join/fetching strategies very unpredictable when used with the query cache.** Apparently, if NHibernate sees that a query is cached, it will make *no effort whatsoever* to check first if *all* or even *any* of the actual entities are cached. It pretty much just assumes that they are, and tries to load each one up individually.

This is the reason for the SELECT N+1 disaster; it wouldn't be that big of a deal if NH noticed that the entities weren't in the second-level cache and just executed the query normally, as written, with fetches and futures and so on. But it doesn't do that; instead it tries to load every entity, and its relations, and its sub-relations, and its sub-sub-relations, and so on, *one at a time*.

So there is almost no point in using the query cache unless you've explicitly enabled caching for *all* of the entities in the *entire* graph, and even then, you'll want to be very careful (by way of expirations, dependencies, etc.) that cached queries don't outlast the entities that they are supposed to retrieve, otherwise you will just end up making the performance worse.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the SELECT N+1 disaster/unfun behavior with joins/fetches still a thing in 2024? Also, I wish I could upvote this answer twice. By far the most in depth explanation I've seen on caching in NHibernate.

Answer (score 4):

a cached query only stores the IDs of the entities, not the values of the entity. within a cached entity only the IDs of related entities are cached. therefore if you don't cache all the involved entities as well as marking the related entities as cached you could end up with select n+1.

Comment: What do you mean by "marking the related entities as cached"? How does one do that? Ayende makes the same vague reference in his comments but doesn't give any examples...

Comment: @JasonMeckley: I've got the same problem and have tried all the suggestions found on the internet. Could you, please, elaborate?