# Fluent nHibernate L2 Caching Not Working On HasMany Items

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I’m wondering if I have mis-understood how the L2 caching works. I am trying to cache a ‘HasMany(x => x.Posts)’, Bascially I have a topic that has many posts under it - I was under the impression that if I added the following at the top of my topic map

```
Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();
```

its caches map and hasManys until either the underlying data changes of app is restarted?  I have my L2 cache configured like so

```
Fluently.Configure()
.Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("MyAppConString")))
.Cache(c => c.ProviderClass<SysCacheProvider>().UseQueryCache())
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MembershipUserMap>())
Etc…etc..
```

In my Topic map I have the following (I have removed a load of the normal maps to shorten it), and you can see the HasMany on the posts.

```
    public TopicMap()
    {
        Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();

        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        *lots of other normal maps*

        References(x => x.Category).Column("Category_Id");
        References(x => x.User).Column("MembershipUser_Id");
        References(x => x.LastPost).Column("Post_Id").Nullable();

        HasMany(x => x.Posts)
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().KeyColumn("Topic_Id")
            .Inverse();

    *And a few other HasManys*
    }
```

So if I grab all topics, loop over and do the following

```
Topic.Posts.Count()
```

Using SqlProfiler I see the get all posts for each topic (First hit), but if I reload the page I still see all the gets posts for topic queries??

Am I missing something?? I thought this should be cached now??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ayende](http://ayende.com/blog/) has [a good post](http://ayende.com/blog/4046/nhibernate-beware-of-inadvisably-applied-caching-strategies) explaining the same problem that you have run into.

Basically, what you have there is caching only IDs of Posts, not the posts itself. Notice that you have enabled caching for `Topic` entities, but you probably didn't do the same for `Post` entities in `PostMap`.

Add `Cache.ReadWrite()` to `PostMap` also.

Notice that NHibernate won't be able to do the collection caching right in most of the cases if you are using eager loading with `Fetch.Join()`, like you have in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316543/fluent-nhibernate-getting-hasmany-items-in-single-query).

Here's [a very good overview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8766437/119230) of the caching and the problems you might have with eager loading collections.

Comment: Thanks I already had 'Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();' on the PostMap too, I'll have a look at the post.