# Fluent nHibernate Getting HasMany Items In Single Query

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a Topic map which has many posts in it i.e… (At the bottom HasMany(x => x.Posts))

```
 public TopicMap()
{
    Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();

    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Name);
    *lots of other normal maps*

    References(x => x.Category).Column("Category_Id");
    References(x => x.User).Column("MembershipUser_Id");
    References(x => x.LastPost).Column("Post_Id").Nullable();

    HasMany(x => x.Posts)
        .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().KeyColumn("Topic_Id")
        .Inverse();

*And a few other HasManys*
}
```

I have written a query which gets the latest paged topics, loops through and displays data and some posts data (Like the count of child posts etc..) . Here is the query

```
    public PagedList<Topic> GetRecentTopics(int pageIndex, int pageSize, int amountToTake)
    {
        // Get a delayed row count
        var rowCount = Session.QueryOver<Topic>()
                        .Select(Projections.RowCount())
                        .Cacheable().CacheMode(CacheMode.Normal)
                        .FutureValue<int>();

        var results = Session.QueryOver<Topic>()
                            .OrderBy(x => x.CreateDate).Desc
                            .Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
                            .Take(pageSize)
                            .Cacheable().CacheMode(CacheMode.Normal)
                            .Future<Topic>().ToList();

        var total = rowCount.Value;
        if (total > amountToTake)
        {
            total = amountToTake;
        }

        // Return a paged list
        return new PagedList<Topic>(results, pageIndex, pageSize, total);
    }
```

When I use SQLProfiler on this, as I loop over the topics is does a db hit to grab all Posts from the parent topic. So if I have 10 topics, I get 10 DB hits as it grabs the posts.

Can I change this query to grab the posts as well in a single query? I guess some sort of Join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define eager fetching using `Fetch.xxx` on your `HasMany` property mapping. Available options are `Fetch.Join()`, `Fetch.Select()` and `Fetch.SubSelect()`. More info on each type of fetching can be found on NHibernate's [documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching).

```
HasMany(x => x.Posts)
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().KeyColumn("Topic_Id")
    .Fetch.Join()
    .Inverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way is defining a reasonable `batch-size` for the collection (rule of thumb: your default parent page size)

That way, after getting the parent items, you'll get a single query for each child collection type you iterate.

Comment: Thats what I currently have, I was just trying to reduce the child collection calls as the 'amount per page' is user settable so they 'could' add 50 etc..

Comment: I don't see any batch size setting in your mapping.