# NHibernate SysCache2 and the Query Cache - Cannot avoid a Select N+1?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, syscache2

I'm using the second level cache provider SysCache2 with Fluent NHibernate, using a standard fluent configuration (with query cache enabled as seems to be the general advice), and having table based dependencies defined in the usual manner.

Fluent:

```cs
config.Cache(c => c
 .ProviderClass<NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2.SysCacheProvider>()
 .UseQueryCache()
 .UseSecondLevelCache()
 .UseMinimalPuts()
```

)

Web.Config:

```cs
  <cacheRegion name="User" relativeExpiration="7200">
<dependencies>
  <tables>
    <add name="User" databaseEntryName="OldClient" tableName="tbl_users" />
  </tables>
</dependencies>
```

User Mapping:

```cs
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("Users");
        ....
        // caching
        Cache.IncludeAll().ReadWrite().Region("Users");
    }
}
```

Everything runs as expected for single requests, ie:

```cs
Session<User>.Get()
```

as would be expected from the way that [NHibernate caches by ID](http://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id). Subsequent requests don't hit the database, and invalidating the record in the database causes the Entity to be invalidated, resulting in a subsequent SQL call during the next request. All ok.

The problem is with query caching. In the first instance, everything works fine. Executing a call such as:

```cs
Session<User>.Query(item => item.Active == true)
```

results in a SQL call as you would expect (SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Active = true). And subsequent executions result in no SQL. Great. Until such a time when a single record from the query set is changed in the database. Executing the same query then results in a SELECT N+1:

```cs
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = 1
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = 2
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = 3
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = 4
...
```

I've found references to this elsewhere, although no solutions:

[StackOverflow - How do I make NHibernate cache fetched child collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761249/how-do-i-make-nhibernate-cache-fetched-child-collections) See the 'one more point' section

[Ayende Caching Strategies](http://ayende.com/blog/4046/nhibernate-beware-of-inadvisably-applied-caching-strategies) he mentions ensuring 'entities are also cached' at the end

The only way I can avoid this at the moment is to clear the query cache after every request - which almost renders it useless. What I need to for the query cache to clear everything for a particular Entity when that entity is invalidated - not just the individual records.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to both links you posted, the query cache caches the IDs resulting from the query and starts fetching entities one by one: if you have them in your cache, great, if not, bad luck, you now have many selects.

At this point I presume that the entities that you are selecting are not in the second level cache (anymore?). I never used table based dependencies, we are using [command based dependencies](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#d0e13990), and I just tested that if an entity is marked as invalid, only this cached entity, and not the whole cache region, is thrown out of the cache.

Check the configuration to be sure that it is correct, maybe when you think you are hitting the second level cache you are actually hitting the session cache? Be sure that you are testing that the cache is working *across* different sessions.

In any case I advise you to look into the DEBUG level logs of NHibernate and see what is actually happening with the second level cache, there you will be able to see all cache hits/misses. Another tip I can give you is to enable the generate_statistics flag in your configuration. Fluent:

```
config.ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty("generate_statistics", "true"));
```

After this you can access interesting data in the session factory such as `Session.SessionFactory.Statistics.SecondLevelCacheMissCount` and `Session.SessionFactory.Statistics.SecondLevelCacheHitCount`. With the combination of these two methods you should be able to pinpoint the cause of the problem.